# Android fireabase auth: Add multiple emails to the same Firebase auth account

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

what I'm trying to achieve is adding two emails to the same account with the same password, for example the user creates the account with the following information

**email = a.a@a.com**

**password = 123456**

then they add another email to their account

**email b.b@b.com**

when the user logs in he can enter either email a.a@a.com or b.b@b.com with the password 123456 and log in, is such a thing possible in firebase Auth? if not then can we create two accounts with the UID? I'm trying to achieve this in kotlin, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  When using email/password authentication, there can only be one, unique email address used for that account at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am trying to allow users to change emails, I know I just update the email, but what if the user changes to a fake email? something like a.b@c.com, I don't think it is a wise thing to change the email then send a verification email, so I thought of adding another email then letting the user remove the old email but since it is not possible is there a way to send a verification email to the new account? after the user verifies the new account then he can progress with updating (replacing) current email